# How to fetch Id of custom views(drawings done using canvas) in monkeytalk and automate it?

Tags: android, canvas, automated-tests, monkeytalk

How do we test custom views in monkeytalk?(android and ios application automation)I have tried giving content description to some views and fetch id, it works fine, but when it comes to some complex views that involves canvas drawing , I am not able to fetch id!!Please can anyone suggest how to go about it?

Below is the android code snippet that I am using

```
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    myPaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.dialerFontColorDark));
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    android.graphics.Path timePointer = new android.graphics.Path();

    // Draws the upper arrow on the top of the temperature box
    timePointer.moveTo(dialCenterX - getDip(6),
            (dialCenterY - this.dialRadius) - getDip(32));
    timePointer.lineTo(dialCenterX, (dialCenterY - this.dialRadius)
            - getDip(20));
    timePointer.lineTo(dialCenterX + getDip(6),
            (dialCenterY - this.dialRadius) - getDip(32));
    timePointer.close();
    *canvas.drawPath(timePointer, myPaint);*
    timePointer.reset();
```

How do we fetch id for the canvas drawn in monkeytalk?

Comment: I'd suggest adding proper tag (android or ios - I guess the question is related to mobile phones) so that your question reaches people watching those tags. Also you should be more concrete, write what exactly doesn't work. Note that I will not be able to answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if anyone would try to answer with possible solutions